# On click search and go cell in workbook

Tags: search, hyperlink, tags, excel

I would like to know if anyone can help me on this one.

I have a workbook with several tabs and a main page.

On the main page i have a top 20 of issues that are populated automatically.
What i want to do is to automatically create hyperlinks on the "number" row, and when i click them to search that number in the workbook and go to as well. Similar to the CTRL+F.

```
Number - Problem - Status   
IM123
IM124
IM145
ETC..
```

can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, you can use something like this to search for the data

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Cells.Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                   xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   After:=ActiveCell, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
End If
```

this moves to the next cell containing the same data as the cell you have clicked in, as long as you are in the specified range *(A1:A4)* and you have only selected one cell *(Target.Count=1)*

Answer (score 0):

The following will search for whatever number is in the cell you have selected.
In addition to finding the first result, it will ask if you want to continue searching for the next result. That way, if you have multiple instances of an issue, you can "loop" through all of the results that are found in the worksheet. It will also ignore search results found on your MainWorksheet containing your top 20 issues. Cells.Find by itself will simply return the first result found, even if it is in the same worksheet.

It will also tell you whether or not the issue number was found in each sheet, and when all of the worksheets have been checked (in case no more results are found). If you respond that you don't want to continue searching, it will go to the first instance of the issue number that was found in the most recent worksheet that was checked.

In order to simulate a hyperlink, you need to use a worksheet event such as Intersect (described in Sean's answer) or FollowHyperlink. Personally, I prefer to use alternatives to worksheet events where possible, as they will always trigger when the condition is met, even if unintentionally. For example, you could create a shape or macro button and assign the macro to it. That way, the code will only run when the user clicks on the button.

Also, please let us know if there is more that you really want to do once you've identified the issue. For example, you could automatically make changes to related cells, or create a list of all of the instances of that issue (or all issues) that were found.

Good luck!

```
'Create a string variable to store the problem status
    Dim StringProblemStatus As String

'Create a string variable to store the worksheet name of the main page containing the problem status
    Dim StringMainWorksheet

'Create a range variable to store the results of the Find method
    Dim RangeFindResults As Range

'Create an integer variable to store the current worksheet number
    Dim IntegerSheetCount As Integer

'Set the variable to the problem status stored in the current cell
    StringProblemStatus = Selection.Value

'Set the variable to the worksheet name containing the problem status
    StringMainWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Create a For/Next loop so that the following code will evaluate all worksheets in the workbook
    For IntegerSheetCount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(IntegerSheetCount).Activate

'Search for the problem number within the worksheet

        'Check that the sheet being searched is not the MainWorksheet
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> StringMainWorksheet Then

            'Searches for exact matches
            Set RangeFindResults = _
            Cells.Find( _
            What:=StringProblemStatus, _
            After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False _
            )

            'Returns a message to the user if the status is not found
            If RangeFindResults Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Problem Status " & StringProblemStatus & " was not found in worksheet " & Sheets(IntegerSheetCount).Name
            Else

                'Returns a message to the user if the status is found
                If MsgBox("Problem Status " & RangeFindResults & " found in worksheet " & _
                Sheets(IntegerSheetCount).Name & " in cell " & " " & RangeFindResults.Address & _
                ". Continue searching?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

                    RangeFindResults.Activate 
                    Exit Sub

                End If

            End If

        End If

    'Move to the next worksheet
    Next IntegerSheetCount

    'Notify the user that all worksheets have been searched
    MsgBox "All worksheets searched"

End Sub
```